# How to Make Bootstrap 3 Thumbnail Background Transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, thumbnails

I want to make the the Backgrounds of the Thumbnails transparent.

I have tried overwriting the CSS by the using the following code combinations:

First:

```
    .thumbnail{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);   
    background-color: #000;}
```

Second:

```
    .thumbnail{
     background-color:transparent;  
     background: transparent;}
```

None of this seems to work.

Comment: Bootstrap `img` classes don't have backgrounds, what exactly are you trying to make transparent? http://jsfiddle.net/4Lt0qqx6/

Comment: the background color of a thumbnail class in a column - that if i am correct is set to white by default

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap thumbnails are `.img-thumbnail`, not `.thumbnail`, and you make them transparent by overwriting like so:

```
.img-thumbnail{background-color:transparent}
```

DEMO: http://www.bootply.com/nsKUpFuaH8

Answer (score 2):

Add a style to the div like so

```
<div class='thumbnail' style='background-color: transparent'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Please make sure that you were using `.png` images

CSS:

```
.thumbnail{
     border:none !important;
     background: transparent !important;
     box-shadow:none !important;
  }
```